# Google Tag Manager and Content Security Policy

Tags: google-tag-manager, content-security-policy

I am trying to implement Content Security Policy on my website. But when I am implementing script-src it is giving me this error.

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXX' because it violates the following
```

My Content Security Policy is

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js https://www.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js/  https://tagmanager.google.com/http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js https://*.google.com;
```

Comment: Instructions are here: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/csp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove trailing slash in the `https://*.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js/` because CSP consider it a folder but really it's a file. More reliable is to specify just `https://*.googletagmanager.com` without path/filename.
2. Insert a space between `https://tagmanager.google.com/` and `http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js` because your specify incorrect host-source: `https://tagmanager.google.com/http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js`.

*Note 1*: host-source `http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js` is covered by the `https://*.google.com` (falls under the that template).

*Note 2*: `script-src 'unsafe-inline'` does not protect against XSS. Consider not using `'unsafe-inline'` in the `script-src` directive.

Comment: For that last sentence, you cannot disallow inline scripts if you intend to use Custom HTML tags or custom Javascript variables. Since this would render the protection by the CSP pretty much moot, Google has introduced Custom Templates (which unlike custom tags do not rely on eval).

Comment: Yes, the problem you described exists. But `'unsafe-inline'` is required only if you use custom inline scripts in the «Custom HTML tag». `'unsafe-eval'` is require only when custom JavaScript variable names are used in the «Custom HTML tag». Using "Custom Templates" allow to get rid of `'unsafe-eval'`, but not `'unsafe-inline'`.

Comment: So if you do not use above Custom HTML tag's features you can use nonces to avoid `'unsafe-inline'`. GTM redistributes nonce to all scripts except script in Custom HTML tags. In some cases, for instance in the Electron apps, you can use `"strict-dynamic'`  + `'hash-value'` to allow inline scripts in the Custom HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
script-src *.googletagmanager.com;
```

to you content policy to make an exception for the GTAG.